app does not work after separating with the Google Play bundle
I have an app that uses native code.
('x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a')
It works fine when I get full or per-processor output.
But when I send the bundle to Google. The file created by google play for any other processor does not work properly!
What I did to solve the problem:
I tried to create a bundle for only one processor. But Google did not accept it because the program must be able to work for both 32 and 64 bit types of processors.
Is there a way I can tell Google not to shred the app?

What's the error? In the logcat

i'm using firebase Crashlytics . but it does not record any error!

So you can't reproduce the error? Does it crash for all your users or only a small fraction?

i realized we have error on real phones but same apk work well on pc virtual device!
its a vpn app . when its make vpnservice it seems well but it cant tunnel any trafic

Random thought. Keep in mind that Google signs the APKs generated from the App Bundle with a different key than the one you have on your computer, so if you're referencing the certificate of the key anywhere in the manifest or expect requests from a given certificate in your server, you should use Google's certificate and not yours.

no sir , google universal apk is work fine . problem is here when make apk for each processor. app does not work fine (vpn not working).
